# Where does signal handler return back to?

Tags: c, linux

Say that a process is running within the main method when a signal is received and handled. When the signal handler is finished, does the process return back to the line in main where the signal was received, or does it return to the signal call?

P.S. I know I can test this quickly myself but this thought occurred to me while I am without access to my PC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It returns back to where it was in your code when the signal was triggered.

Many libraries and applications exploit the same mechanisms to implement threadless multitasking (for instance [libmill](http://libmill.org/)).

Comment: And by "where it was called" I presume you mean the spot in code when/where the signal was received? As opposed to the call to the signal function? Sorry, I'm new to signals and would like to be extra clear, as this will determine how I write my program.

Comment: Yeah. I've tweaked the wording.

Answer (score 3):

After the signal handler completes, your code continues executing at the point where it was when the signal was received. If your code was executing a system call, it may fail with EINTR. See signal(7) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

**If it was raised by `raise` it continues just after the `raise()`**

More precisely, the Linux kernel returns to the very first instruction after the `syscall` instruction.

Let's GDB it.

signal_return.c

```
#include <stdio.h> /* puts */
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT_SUCCESS */
#include <signal.h> /* signal, raise, SIGSEGV */

#include <unistd.h> /* write, STDOUT_FILENO */

void signal_handler(int sig) {
    (void)sig;
    const char msg[] = "signal received\n";
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof(msg));
    /* The handler automatically disables handling of future signals.
     * So we set it again here. */
    signal(SIGSEGV, signal_handler);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    (void)argv;
    signal(SIGSEGV, signal_handler);
    if (argc > 1) {
        *(int *)0 = 1;
    } else {
        raise(SIGSEGV);
    }
    puts("after");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o signal_return.out signal_return.c
```

Run without arguments to do a `raise(SIGSEGV);`:

```
./signal_return.out
```

output:

```
signal received
after
```

Now I run it through GDB with [GDB Dashboar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902901/show-current-assembly-instruction-in-gdb/55935724#55935724) to make it easier to interpret things:

```
gdb \
  -ex 'set pagination off' \
  -ex 'handle all nostop' \
  -ex 'dashboard -layout source assembly' \
  -ex 'b signal_handler' \
  -ex 'run' \
  -ex 'fin' \
  signal_return.out
```

`handle all nostop` stops GDB from stopping at signals for us: [How to handle all signals in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999208/how-to-handle-all-signals-in-gdb)

After the `fin` we are left in some internal signal handling machinery, so I just `ni` a bunch of times.

The first time we come out back to main is:

```
26     puts("after");
27     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
28 }
─── Assembly ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
0x0000555555555280 main+56 jmp    0x55555555528c <main+68>
0x0000555555555282 main+58 mov    $0xb,%edi
0x0000555555555287 main+63 call   0x555555555090 <raise@plt>
0x000055555555528c main+68 lea    0xd71(%rip),%rax        # 0x555555556004
0x0000555555555293 main+75 mov    %rax,%rdi
0x0000555555555296 main+78 call   0x5555555550a0 <puts@plt>
0x000055555555529b main+83 mov    $0x0,%eax
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>>>
```

we are at the `lea`. We can see where that fits into `main` with:

```
disas /m
```

which gives:

```
18      int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   0x0000555555555248 <+0>:     endbr64 
   0x000055555555524c <+4>:     push   %rbp
   0x000055555555524d <+5>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000555555555250 <+8>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000555555555254 <+12>:    mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555257 <+15>:    mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)

19          (void)argv;
20          signal(SIGSEGV, signal_handler);
   0x000055555555525b <+19>:    lea    -0x99(%rip),%rax        # 0x5555555551c9 <signal_handler>
   0x0000555555555262 <+26>:    mov    %rax,%rsi
   0x0000555555555265 <+29>:    mov    $0xb,%edi
   0x000055555555526a <+34>:    call   0x5555555550d0 <__sysv_signal@plt>

21          if (argc > 1) {
   0x000055555555526f <+39>:    cmpl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555273 <+43>:    jle    0x555555555282 <main+58>

22              *(int *)0 = 1;
   0x0000555555555275 <+45>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000055555555527a <+50>:    movl   $0x1,(%rax)
   0x0000555555555280 <+56>:    jmp    0x55555555528c <main+68>

23          } else {
24              raise(SIGSEGV);
   0x0000555555555282 <+58>:    mov    $0xb,%edi
   0x0000555555555287 <+63>:    call   0x555555555090 <raise@plt>

25          }
26          puts("after");
=> 0x000055555555528c <+68>:    lea    0xd71(%rip),%rax        # 0x555555556004
   0x0000555555555293 <+75>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000555555555296 <+78>:    call   0x5555555550a0 <puts@plt>

27          return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   0x000055555555529b <+83>:    mov    $0x0,%eax

28      }
   0x00005555555552a0 <+88>:    leave  
   0x00005555555552a1 <+89>:    ret
```

so it is clear that we returned to the very first instruction after the call to the C library function `signal`:

```
call   0x555555555090 <raise@plt>
```

This appears to happen right at the instruction level. By using: https://askubuntu.com/questions/487222/how-to-install-debug-symbols-for-installed-packages/1434174#1434174 we can step into `raise` until the syscall with some effort:

```
0x00007ffff7e07a7a __pthread_kill_implementation+240 syscall
0x00007ffff7e07a7c __pthread_kill_implementation+242 mov    %eax,%r13d
```

After +240 we go into the signal. And after the signal handler returns, the very first instruction executed is +242. TODO: compile a minimal freestanding assembly example to finish it off ;-)

**If it was raised by an instruction, it goes back and re-runs the instruction**

Running the program with an argument:

```
./signal_return.out 1
```

leads to an infinite loop of:

```
signal received
signal received
signal received
```

We therefore understand that we must be going back to the very offending instruction.

Let's try to walk into the instruction ourselves this time:

```
gdb \
  -ex 'set pagination off' \
  -ex 'handle all nostop' \
  -ex 'dashboard -layout source assembly' \
  -ex 'b signal_handler' \
  -ex 'start' \
  -args signal_return.out 1
```

We are trying to write to address 0 at line 22:

```
18 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
19     (void)argv;
20     signal(SIGSEGV, signal_handler);
21     if (argc > 1) {
22         *(int *)0 = 1;
23     } else {
24         raise(SIGSEGV);
25     }
26     puts("after");
27     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
28 }
─── Assembly ─────────────────────────────────────────────
0x000055555555526f main+39 cmpl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
0x0000555555555273 main+43 jle    0x555555555282 <main+58>
0x0000555555555275 main+45 mov    $0x0,%eax
0x000055555555527a main+50 movl   $0x1,(%rax)
```

Now after I `si` here, we hit the breakpoint.

After I `fin` we are left at a weird:

```
0x00007ffff7db3520 __restore_rt+0 mov    $0xf,%rax
0x00007ffff7db3527 __restore_rt+7 syscall 
0x00007ffff7db3529 __restore_rt+9 nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

which makes system call number 0xf = 15. A quick peek at the syscall table teaches us that this is `rt_sigreturn`, and `man rt_sigreturn` tells us a bit about the code injection madness done by the kernel.

After two more `si`s we are out and back to the exact offending instruction:

```
22         *(int *)0 = 1;
23     } else {
24         raise(SIGSEGV);
25     }
26     puts("after");
27     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
28 }
─── Assembly ─────────────────────────────────────────────
0x000055555555526f main+39 cmpl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
0x0000555555555273 main+43 jle    0x555555555282 <main+58>
0x0000555555555275 main+45 mov    $0x0,%eax
0x000055555555527a main+50 movl   $0x1,(%rax)
```

**Returning to the offending instruction allows us both to handle the signal and get a core dump**

As mentioned at: [Linux: handling a segmentation fault and getting a core dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697361/linux-handling-a-segmentation-fault-and-getting-a-core-dump/74653236#74653236) this default behavior is not bad, because what you might want to do on `SIGSEGV` is:

- print a stack trace from your handler: [How to automatically generate a stacktrace when my program crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-automatically-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-program-crashes)
- go back to the instruction and blow up, generating a correct core dump that can be later examined for even more detail, notably to extract values of variables on the call stack with GDB: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89933/how-to-view-core-files-for-debugging-purposes-in-linux/202443#202443 We wouldn't be able to generate a correct dump from inside the handler ourselves, as we are in a different stack state.

For this to work like that you would want to remove the `signal(SIGSEGV, signal_handler);` call from the handler. This way it comes out and blows up as desired instead of looping forever. That was only for demonstration purposes.

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04 x86_64.