# How to make Check generate a core dump?

Tags: c, unit-testing, segmentation-fault, coredump

I have a unit test (using [Check](http://libcheck.github.io/check/)) that is crashing. How do I generate a core dump so I can debug it?

```
$ make check
.
.
.
XXX.c:216:E:Core:test01XXX:0: (after this point) Received signal 11 (Segmentation fault)
```

(Line 216 is just the beginning of test01XXX, not an actual line of code)

I have tried `ulimit -c unlimited` but there is no core file.

Edit: I don't think this is an issue with writing a core file in general or finding it on disk. From the same directory, I can `kill -SEGV` a process and it will generate a core file:

```
$ ls core*
ls: cannot access core*: No such file or directory
$ cat crash.c
int main()
{
    return *(int *)0;
}
$ gcc -o crash crash.c
$ ./crash
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ ls core*
core.121934
```

I think the issue is that Check traps the SIGSEGV, and I just need to configure it differently somehow.

Comment: maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732983/core-dump-file-is-not-generated

Comment: what give `find . -name "*core*" -print` ?

Comment: @user1034749 no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the *What is Check?* section on the [front page](https://libcheck.github.io/check/), it defaults to running tests "in a separate address space" (i.e., in a child process), so they can't damage the unit test framework itself.

However, [No Fork Mode](https://libcheck.github.io/check/doc/check_html/check_4.html#No-Fork-Mode) is provided for precisely this reason:

> However, when you are trying to debug why the segmentation fault or other program error occurred, forking makes it difficult to use debugging tools

Set or export `CK_FORK=no` while you're figuring out this crash.

If you find some test that should always give you a core on failure, you can control it programmatically with

```
srunner_set_fork_status (..., CK_NOFORK);
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks! I ran `CK_FORK=no make check` and now have a coredump.